# How a reply system works on a aircraft transponder?

Tags: software-defined-radio, transceiver

I'm trying to build a transponder ramp test for mode c and s of aircrafts for my degree.

I have a problem, I didn't understand reply system of transponde, how can I doba reply of a signal to test one?

Comment: Welcome! This is a very short description for something that will be fairly complicated. How far have you gotten? Have you written some user requirements for the test system - what should it do, what should it not do? Are you planning to actually build it, or just design it?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you go to the Eurocontrol website.
Have a look for Asterix category 048. This is the definition for the Mode A Octal code for aircraft transponder, Mode C altitude, Mode S more data including callsign ICAO 24 bit identify code and lots more. There will lots of information about the radar calling and aircraft response exchanges as well.
Former air traffic controller, currently testing air traffic controller systems.